# Applying 'categories' to Y-Axis causes a gap between column start and X Axis in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, web, highcharts

I am setting up a simple column chart using Highcharts. After applying categories to my Y-Axis it causes my columns to raise off the x-axis.

I initially was using a chart someone else started with, however couldn't fix it and even after altering a few different fields on my chart. Notably, min and max, however I also tried a few others I found in the docs regarding spacing etc.

So I took a chart from the Highcharts documentation and explictly edited it to my needs. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-basic/) is the starting chart I began with. I edited each field to slowly turn it into the graph I need.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Bar Title'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [
            'Category 1',
            'Category 2',
            'Category 3',
            'Category 4',
        ]
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: '',
        categories: ['', 'Cat 1', 'Cat 2', 'Cat 3', 'Cat 4', 'Cat 5'],
        min: 0,
        max: 5,
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Score',
        data: [1, 2, 3, 4]

    }, {
        name: 'Average Score',
        data: [5, 4, 4, 4]

    }]
});
```

This is as close as I can get. However, as noted by this image, there is a gap between my column and my x-axis.

[image: 'As close as I can get it']

If I remove the below line:

```
categories: ['', 'Cat 1', 'Cat 2', 'Cat 3', 'Cat 4', 'Cat 5'],
```

It gets a lot closer!

[image: 'Almost there']

I'm just looking for a way to keep my Y-axis labels and have no gap. Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have categories on the xAxis and yAxis at the same time when you pass data with values. However, you can achieve what you expect using `yAxsi.labels.formatter` callback and mapping values to categories. Check demo and code posted below:

```
var categories = ['', 'Cat 1', 'Cat 2', 'Cat 3', 'Cat 4', 'Cat 5'];

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Bar Title'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: [
      'Category 1',
      'Category 2',
      'Category 3',
      'Category 4',
    ]
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: '',
    min: 0,
    max: 5,
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
        return categories[this.value];
      }
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      pointPadding: 0.2,
      borderWidth: 0
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Score',
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4]
  }, {
    name: 'Average Score',
    data: [5, 4, 4, 4]
  }]
});
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lq6c0mgx/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels.formatter